# How to make a plot of power iteration method approximations

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, iteration

I am trying to make a plot of eigenvalue approximations for first 20 iterations with following code:

```
def metoda_potegowa(A,X0,iterations):

  iteracje=[]
  aproks=[]
  ii=0

  while(1):
    for i in range (iterations):
      A = A*A

    x = A*X0
    aproks.append(x)
    iteracje.append(ii)
    ii=ii+1
    norm = np.linalg.norm(x)

    plt.scatter(iteracje,aproks)
    plt.xlabel('iteracja')
    plt.ylabel('aproksymacja')
    plt.grid
    plt.show

    break

  print (x/norm)
  print (np.linalg.eig(A)[1])
```

I get a warning of:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-d18eef58c53a> in <module>()
----> 1 metoda_potegowa(a,x0,5)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, plotnonfinite, **kwargs)
   4378         y = np.ma.ravel(y)
   4379         if x.size != y.size:
-> 4380             raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
   4381 
   4382         if s is None:

ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

how can I fix this so it draws a plot for me?

Comment: What arguments did you use to call the function?

Comment: metoda_potegowa(a,x0,5) where a = np.matrix([[1, 0, 3], [0, 2, 0], [3, 0, 1]]);
x0 = np.matrix([1,1,1]).transpose();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me tell you that the code

```
while(1):
   code...
   break
```

does not make sense. Because it's the same of just

```
code...
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration), you can calculate the next aproximation of eigenvector using the following formula:

[image]

The axis `iteracje` and `aproks` are bad choices for scatter plot, because we have vectors. How can we represent a vector with a point?
We can choose the following approach:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

def metoda_potegowa(A,X0,iterations):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
    b_k = X0.copy()
    for i, _ in enumerate(range(iterations)):
        # calculate the product between A and b_k
        Ab_k = np.dot(A, b_k)

        # calculate the norm
        Ab_k_norm = np.linalg.norm(Ab_k)

        # get next aproximation of eigenvector
        b_k = Ab_k / Ab_k_norm

        # plot the current iteration i
        plt.scatter(list(range(1, len(b_k)+1)), b_k.ravel(), label=i)
    plt.xlabel('index')
    plt.ylabel('value') 
    # use colors to distinguish iteration
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    return b_k
```

Then you can call the function with `iterations = 20` and plot the result:

```
a = np.array([[1, 0, 3], [0, 2, 0], [3, 0, 1]])
x0 = np.array([1,1,1]).transpose()
eigenvector_20 = metoda_potegowa(a,x0,20)
```

Comment: hm when I call it like you said it gives me an error of : ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 1 has size 1

Comment: can you check the call method you wrote about? it seems that function does not work properly

Comment: It's because I used np.matrix(). I need to use np.array(). I'll edit the answer.